# Discovering members of MUC room as occupant

Tags: xmpp, ejabberd, xmppframework, multiuserchat

As an occupant/member, I need to know all the "members" in the room with ejabberd-14.x

I followed http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0045.html#getmemberlist

I got forbidden (401) for following stanze - Admin privilege required

```
<iq from='crone1@shakespeare.lit/desktop'
    id='member3'
    to='coven@chat.shakespeare.lit'
    type='get'>
  <query xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/muc#admin'>
    <item affiliation='member'/>
  </query>
</iq>
```

If I change

```
<query xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/muc#admin'>
```

from admin to user namespace, then I get status code 501 - Feature not implemented

Would you know how can I get members of a room as an occupant or member?

I am not an admin/moderator in this use case.

XEP-0045 does say:

> Note: A service SHOULD also return the member list to any occupant in
>   a members-only room; i.e., it SHOULD NOT generate a  error
>   when a member in the room requests the member list. This functionality
>   can assist clients in showing all the existing members even if some of
>   them are not in the room, e.g. to help a member determine if another
>   user should be invited. A service SHOULD also allow any member to
>   retrieve the member list even if not yet an occupant.

Answer (score 1):

You need to be at least a member yourself to access the affiliation list. It doesn't matter whether or not you are currently an occupant (ie. in the room).

Note that an affiliation (such as "member") is a persistent setting that needs to be explicitly given to people, who default to "none" otherwise. In a normal unrestricted room, [this setting doesn't have any other effect than allowing you to retrieve the member list](https://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0045.html#affil-priv). The member list is unrelated to the occupant list.

(If you merely want to know who is currently in the room, you should send a query with the namespace `http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#items` instead of `muc#admin`.)

Example (just tried on my ejabberd server). Attempting to query the list with an unaffiliated account:

```
<iq from='crone1@shakespeare.lit/desktop'
    id='member3'
    to='coven@chat.shakespeare.lit'
    type='get'>
  <query xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/muc#admin'>
    <item affiliation='member'/>
  </query>
</iq>
<iq from='coven@chat.shakespeare.lit'
    to='crone1@shakespeare.lit/desktop'
    type='error'
    id='member3'>
  <query xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/muc#admin'>
    <item affiliation='member'/>
  </query>
  <error code='403' type='auth'>
    <forbidden/>
    <text>Administrator privileges required</text>
  </error>
</iq>
```

Using a privileged (room owner) account to grant that first account member privileges:

```
<iq from='admin@shakespeare.lit/desktop'
    type='set'
    to='coven@chat.shakespeare.lit'
    id='member4'>
  <query xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/muc#admin'>
    <item jid='crone1@shakespeare.lit' affiliation='member'/>
  </query>
</iq>

<iq to='admin@shakespeare.lit/desktop'
    from='coven@chat.shakespeare.lit'
    type='result' id='member4'/>
```

Trying again:

```
<iq from='crone1@shakespeare.lit/desktop' 
    type='get'
    to='coven@chat.shakespeare.lit'
    id='member5'>
  <query xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/muc#admin'>
    <item affiliation='member'/>
  </query>
</iq>

<iq to='crone1@shakespeare.lit/desktop'
    from='coven@chat.shakespeare.lit'
    type='result'
    id='member5'>
  <query xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/muc#admin'>
    <item jid='crone1@shakespeare.lit' affiliation='member'/>
  </query>
</iq>
```